# How can I read from a read-only RandomAccessFile while a MediaPlayer is playing from it in a different position

Tags: android, media-player, randomaccessfile

I have a custom file format (similar to a zip file) that packs small files (small images, mp3 files) into 1 physical file. My android app downloads this file, and it displays one image from it. The user can touch the image and it'll start to play one of the small mp3 "files" inside the packed file. He can also swipe left or right, and the app displays the previous or next image.

In order to make things smoother I am holding 3 "cards" in the memory: the one currently displayed, and the prevous and the next one. This way when it's swiped, I can immediatelly show the next image. In order to do this, I am preloading the images and the mp3 into the MediaPlayer. The problem is that because of this it is multi threaded, as the preloading is done in the background. I have a bug: when I start to play the mp3, and during it's playing I swipe, the image I preaload is cut in the middle. After lots of debugging, I found the reason: while I load the image, the MediaPlayer is moving the file pointer in the file descriptor, and that causes the next read to read from the middle of the mp3 instead of the image.

Here's the code:

```
InputStream imageStream = myPackedFile.getBaseStream("cat.jpg"); // this returns an InputStream representing "cat.jpg" from my packed file (which is based on a RandomAccessFile)
Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(imageStream, imagePath);

FileDescriptor fd = myPackedFile.getFD();
long pos = myPackedFile.getPos("cat.mp3");
long len = myPackedFile.getLength("cat.mp3");
player.setDataSource(fd, pos, len);
player.prepare();
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't wish to `dup` i.e. duplicate the `myPackedFile` so that image and `mp3` playback could be mutually exclusive?

Comment: It depends what you mean on duplicate: if copying the physical file to another physical file, then NO! What I would want to do is to "clone" the FileChannel in a way that they point to the same physical file, but the position in the different Channels can be different, and positioning in one channel doesn't affect the other channels

Comment: @Gavriel.. When I meant duplicate, I only meant duplicating the file pointer. There could 2 distinct file pointers to the same file, each reading from different position.

Comment: yes, that's what I'd like to do. How can I do that? Can you send me code?

Comment: @Gavriel.. I haven't programmed much at the `JAVA` layer and have used this functionality on `native` side. I am searching for a `JAVA` example. In the meantime, this link: http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#864 could give you some idea about the concept. Hope this is helpful

Comment: @Ganesh, thanks, but unfortunatelly ParcelFileDescriptor.dup is only in android API level 13 and above, and my app uses API level 9. However +1 for the idea, this is what lead me to the solution posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me: Instead of creating a RandomAccessFile and holding to it, I create a File, and every time I need to access it as a RandomAccessFile I create a new one:

```
public class PackagedFile {
    private File file;
    PackagedFile(String filename) {
        file = new File(filename);
    }
    public RandomAccessFile getRandomAccessFile() {
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        try {
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return raf;
    }
}
```

and the above code became:

```
InputStream imageStream = myPackedFile.getBaseStream("cat.jpg"); // this returns an InputStream representing "cat.jpg" from my packed file (which is based on a RandomAccessFile)
Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(imageStream, imagePath);

FileDescriptor fd = myPackedFile.getRandomAccessFile().getFD();
long pos = myPackedFile.getPos("cat.mp3");
long len = myPackedFile.getLength("cat.mp3");
player.setDataSource(fd, pos, len);
player.prepare();
```

Answer (score 1):

For API Level 13 and above, one can consider `ParcelFileDescriptor.dup` to duplicate the file descriptors. For more information, please refer to this link:  http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#864